# Array identity - is

Tags: arrays, identity, d

I'm having problems understanding array identity in D.

```
Object s = null; // or new Object
auto a = [s];
auto b = [s];
writeln(a is b); // > false
writeln(a == b); // > true
```

This prints `false`, then `true`. I have no problem with `==`, but in the [D2 ref](http://dlang.org/expression.html) it is stated that

> For static and dynamic arrays, identity is defined as referring to the same array elements and the same number of elements.

Which contradicts with the behavior I experience. `a` and `b` both have one element which `is s`, so they should be identical. Am I misinterpreting something?

**Edit:** I was in the wrong believe that *same array elements* meant they compared equal in terms of `is`, which kind of models identity comparison in D.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In D, an array is a tuple of a pointer and a length. The arrays are *identical* if they are the same length and point to the same array. The are *equal* if the contents of what they point to are the same.

In your example, `a` and `b` are equal, but not identical because they don't point to the same array. If they did, modifying `a[0]` would also modify `b[0]`, but it doesn't.

If you had instead:

```
Object s = null;
auto a = [s];
auto b = a;
writeln(a is b); // > true
writeln(a == b); // > true
```

Then they'd both be true because they both refer to the same array. Also, in this case, modifying `a[0]` would modify `b[0]` as well.

The key misunderstanding here is that the array elements are not the same for each array, they just refer to the same elements:

```
            s
            ^
            |
       +----+----+
       |         |
      [0]       [0]
       ^         ^
       |         |
       a         b
```

If they were the same, you would have something like this:

```
            s
            ^
            |
           [0]
            ^
            |
       +----+----+
       |         |
       a         b
```

There's multiple levels of indirection here, which is what's probably causing the confusion.

Comment: I could live with that, but it says `identity is defined as referring to the same *array elements* and the same *number of elements*`. Essentially I'm fighting with the spec here.

Comment: Your arrays do not refer to the same elements. They refer to different elements that just happen to have the same value. `a[0]` is not `b[0]`. Modifying one does not modify the other, so they do not refer to the same elements.

Comment: @PeterAlexander Probably worth explaining in answer explicitly that "same elements" is not "equal elements".

Comment: Actually the arrays refer to the same elements. `a[0] is b[0]` (even for a value other than null). http://ideone.com/ktHTZs. Of course, `&a[0] !is &b[0]`, but don't think thats legal D...

Comment: The array elements *refer* to the same object, but the array elements themselves are not the same, just like two pointers can refer to the same object, but still be separate pointers. I've added a diagram that will hopefully clarify the distinction.

Comment: Ok, then it's just that I thought 'same array elements' was defined in terms of `is`, which it apparently isn't. This is enough for an answer :)